# ASP.NET : AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender hides when clicking on next or previous month or year

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

AjaxControlToolkit CalendarExtender hides when clicking on next or previous month or year.

Whenever I click next month or previous month or select month or year, Calendar disappears. 
I am using it inside a repeater.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/disable-future-and-past-date-of-ajax-calendar-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/

Comment: i've done all this. The issue is when I click on next month or previous month, the Calendar disappears. When I click the text box it shows again with the next or previous month selected

Comment: so you need past dates?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1271082.aspx?calendar+extender+not+showing+all+days

Comment: No. when i click on next month button, the calendar disappears. Ideally it should disappear only when I select a date.

Answer (score 0):

Give clientIDMode="AutoID" for the CalenderExtender control.

Comment: Paste your code once .So that it will be easy to find the solution . when I used clientIdMode="AutoId" its working fine inside the repeater .